# windows10 and raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, windows-10-iot-core

I have a raspberry pi running windows 10(IOT) and it worked fine and everything was OK , after that I installed raspbian on the same SD cards that I used for the windows 10(IOT) and again everything worked fine but now I want to use windows 10(IOT) again , I follow the same procedure that I went through before but I cannot connect to my raspberry pi and I receive the following error when using windows powershell

Enter-PSSession : Connecting to remote server 192.168.1.3 failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot
complete the operation. Verify that the specified computer name is valid, that the computer is accessible over the
network, and that a firewall exception for the WinRM service is enabled and allows access from this computer. By
default, the WinRM firewall exception for public profiles limits access to remote computers within the same local
subnet. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
At line:1 char:2
+ Enter-PSSession -ComputerName 192.168.1.3 -Credential 192.168.1.3\Ad ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo : InvalidArgument: (192.168.1.3:String) [Enter-PSSession], PSRemotingTransportException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CreateRemoteRunspaceFailed

here my raspberry ip address is 192.168.1.3 
I followed the tutorial from this link http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkID=532957 step by step in both tries but I receive two different results, I also turned off my windows firewall and windows defender , but it did not work out.

I really appreciate if anyone could help me on that 
best regards 
Alfred

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this tutorial will help you a lot to access Windows IoT device via PowerShell:
 https://www.hackster.io/AnuragVasanwala/windows-10-iot-core-setting-startup-app-887ed0

This article reveals how to set specific Universal App as startup app but also covers the basic aspects of PowerShell, how to connect to it and some known issue(s).